# protractor not finding items present in DOM in ag-grid 25

Tags: javascript, protractor, ag-grid

I am using protractor to retrieve data from filtered rows of an ag-grid.  In ag-grid 25, objects that are present in the DOM are not being found and are generating script errors.  In the following code the ColumnHambugerMenu for the specified column is clicked.  An error is thrown when trying to click the ColumnFilterIcon even though it exists in the DOM

```
filterSingleEventRow: async function (stringToFilter, columnName) {
    try {
        await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(GridColumnHeader), 12000);
        await ColumnHamburgerMenu(columnName).click();
        await ColumnFilterIcon.click();
        ...
```

where

```
GridColumnHeader = element(by.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "ag-header")]'));
ColumnHamburgerMenu = element(by.xpath('.//div[@col-id= "' + columnName + '"]//span[(@ref= "eMenu")]'));
ColumnFilterIcon = element(by.xpath('//div[(@ref="eHeader")] //span[(@class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter")]'));
```

Comment: Share your html of the dropdown. And try using CSS instead of xpath. Xpaths are not recommended as per protractor style guide

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I needed to set waitForAngularEnable to false before interacting with the grid and set i back to false when finished interacting with the grid